# Find a substring and print it

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have this string

```
$string = "create or replace view COMPLEX_NAME_2 (b21d,21ld21)";
```

I want to get the `COMPLEX_NAME_2` and print it.

Keep in mind that that `COMPLEX_NAME_2` is the sub string I need to find and it changes its value. I don't know how to get the substring in that place in the string—the value of the substring doesn't matter.

I tried

```
$string =~ m/view/gi;
print $';
```

But the problem it is that it prints `(b21d,21ld21)` as well and I need only the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slightly alter your current approach to add a [*capture group* to extract the view name](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlretut#Extracting-matches) from your query.  Then, access that capture group using the special variable `$1` after making the match.

```
$string="create or replace view COMPLEX_NAME_2 (b21d,21ld21)";
if ($string=~m/view\s+(\S+)/) {
    print $1;
} else {
    print "no match";
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: You don't need to quote `$1`. `print $1` is fine.

Comment: You don't need to match any spaces after the capture

Comment: @Borodin While it may not be _necessary_ to match a whitespace character after the view name, in a valid `CREATE VIEW` SQL statement, the name of the view normally would be followed by a space, and then some other stuff.  The OP didn't mention anything other than using presumably valid SQL, so I think we would have been OK leaving the previous regex as is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes, it would have been okay. It would also have been fine to leave the quotes around `"$1"`; it's just sloppy code. Why do you value your right to add any superfluous code you like to your solution?

Comment: @Borodin I originally was capturing `(.*?)\s+` but due to other user's suggestions I changed it to `(\w+)\s+`, leaving the whitespace there, this is why it was there mainly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It would also be better to use `\S` instead of `\w`: remember that the view name may be enclosed in quotes. In fact, it may also contain spaces, but that would be a major fix for an unlikely possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If there are never any spaces in the substring then you can use a capture to save all non-space characters after `view`

Like this

```
if ( $string =~ /view\s+(\S+)/ ) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```